# Surface shader - More transparency for distant points

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, vertex

I am trying to create my first Shader in Unity3D. My goal is to add more alpha to pixels if they are close to some point in world space. But I can't get it right. My pixels are not getting smooth transparency (From min value, to max value), just or min, or max..

Here is my code:

```
Shader "Custom/Shield" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Color (RGB) Alpha (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _TexUsage ("Text usage", Range(0.1, 0.99)) = 0
    _HitPoint ("Hit point", Vector) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    _Distance ("Distance", float) = 4.0
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
    LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM
    // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
    // And generate the shadow pass with instancing support
    #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows alpha
    // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
    #pragma target 3.0

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    half _TexUsage;
    float3 _HitPoint;
    fixed _Distance;

    struct Input {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
        float3 worldPos;
    };

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
        IN.uv_MainTex.x = frac(IN.uv_MainTex.x + frac(_Time.x));
        o.Albedo = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).rgba;

        float dist = distance(_HitPoint, IN.worldPos);
        float minAlpha = 0.2;

        float st = step(_Distance, dist);
        float blend = (dist / _Distance) * (1 - st) + minAlpha * st;
        o.Alpha = blend;
    }
    ENDCG
}
FallBack "Diffuse"
```

}

And here is a example how it works now: [image]

But this area should be less visible, if not so close to hit point.

What am I am doing wrong?